# Get the value of a radio input when clicked with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to get the value of a radio input on click to store and display in a summary at the end of the form, before it is submitted. I don't have access to add a click function to the input directly so I am looping through the inputs and adding a click event. Now, I just need to get the value of the clicked input. Here is the code:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('fields');
    for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++)
    {
        radios[i].addEventListener("click", getValue);
    }
function getValue(){
    console.log(radios.value);
    }
```

The response I'm getting is undefined.

Comment: try `this.value`

Comment: Follow up question; how do I get access to my value so I can use it elsewhere? I tried this but it's not working `var radios = document.getElementsByName('fields');
 for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++)
 {
  radios[i].addEventListener("click", getValue);
 }
function getValue(){
 var value= this.value;
 return value;
 }
var value_input = getValue();`

Comment: you cannot return value from event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`radios` doesn't have a `value`. If you want the get the value of the clicked radio, use `this.value`.

Comment: *facepalm* yep, that's it.

Comment: Follow up question, I can log the value but how can I use it outside of the getValue function?

Comment: @shacker define `var currentValue = null` outside `getValue()`. And inside it `currentValue = this.value`. Then you could access `currentValue` outside `getValue()`. Not the cleanest solution, but I don't know what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't use the `'click'` event**. An Input's state can **change** even without a `click` (i.e: tabbing and using spacebar, etc)

Use `'change'` or `'input'` Event

```js
const el_radio_1 = document.querySelectorAll('[name="radio_1"]');
const fn_radio_1 = evt => {
  console.log(evt.target.value)
};

el_radio_1.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('change', fn_radio_1)
});
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio_1" value="a"> Test a 
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio_1" value="b" checked> Test b
</label>
```

If you use standard `Function` use `this.value` :

```
function fn_radio_1(evt)  {
  console.log(this.value)
  console.log(evt.type)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have your html like:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</label> 
<label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</label>
```

then you can get the value of selected radio button like:

```
$("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
```

Comment: Thanks, but looking for a JS solution.